# Python Importing Modules From Different Folder without sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

For the **millionth** time, this question has been asked many times but all the answers are to mess around with `sys.path`. Can someone suggest me the perfect way to arrange my importing?
The following is my project structure:

```
MyProject-
- config.yaml  
- data  
- docs  
- logs
- package_a
  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
- package_b 
  - __init__.py
  - file2.py 
- requirements.txt
```

I want to import `file1` in `file2.py`

`file2.py` looks like this:

```
from package_a.file1 import some_function
```

Now whenever I run `file2.py` like this: `python package_b/file2.py` from the `MyProject` directory. I get the following error: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_a'`.

Why is importing so counter intuitive in python? Please give a clear explanation on how to solve this please?

Comment: you can import like this but it depends on the current working directory

Comment: @luigigi my current working directory is `MyProject` as I've mentioned. But the above doesn't work unless I've explicitly appended the absolute path to `MyProject` in `sys.path`

Comment: are you sure? put this `import os; print(os.getcwd())` above your imports and check if it really is your project

Comment: @luigigi yes, my current directory is /absolute path to MyProject. I've checked.

Comment: Are you running your code from a specific environment? Or are you plainly running a script in MyProject from the terminal?

Comment: @Jalo I'm running the code from the terminal, with this command `python package_b/file2.py` from MyProject folder.

Comment: ok, i missread your question. you might have to go back a directory like `from ..package_a.file1 import some_function`. and btw it is a common way to append a directory to the path. its not messing around with it

Comment: @luigigi `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. This is what i got. Supposedly, `package_b` is the top-level package

Comment: @shaikmoeed appending the current directory to sys.path works. But it feels like a hack, I was looking for more cleaner solution.

Comment: Then you need to install your package. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package)

Comment: I agree with shaik, whether you install the package or you append it to sys.pah. There are no other clean solutions to it as far as I know.

Comment: I've appended the path for now, anyway I'll leave this open for any alternate methods.